# Draw a sphere in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

There are a lot of example codes and questions concerning Tikz, but I can't find exactly what I want.
I want to draw a 3D sphere, but as the following figure illustrates something is wrong. The arc doesn't match the 3D plot.

[image: Sphere doesn't match arc]

I used the following code, based on Hein:

```
%% Copyright 2009 Jeffrey D. Hein
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
% The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
% version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status `maintained'.
% 
% The Current Maintainer of this work is Jeffrey D. Hein.
%
% This work consists of the files 3dplot.sty and 3dplot.tex

%Description
%-----------
%3dplot.tex - an example file demonstrating the use of the 3dplot.sty package.

%Created 2009-11-07 by Jeff Hein.  Last updated: 2009-11-09
%----------------------------------------------------------

%Update Notes
%------------

%2009-11-07: Created file along with 3dplot.sty package


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}   %TikZ is required for this to work.  Make sure this exists before the next line

\usepackage{3dplot} %requires 3dplot.sty to be in same directory, or in your LaTeX installation

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}  %generates a tightly fitting border around the work
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2mm}

\begin{document}

%Angle Definitions
%-----------------

%set the plot display orientation
%synatax: \tdplotsetdisplay{\theta_d}{\phi_d}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}

%define polar coordinates for some vector
%TODO: look into using 3d spherical coordinate system
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rvec}{.8}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\thetavec}{45}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\phivec}{60}

%start tikz picture, and use the tdplot_main_coords style to implement the display 
%coordinate transformation provided by 3dplot
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,tdplot_main_coords]

\shadedraw[tdplot_screen_coords,ball color = white] (0,0) circle (\rvec);

%set up some coordinates 
%-----------------------
\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);

%determine a coordinate (P) using (r,\theta,\phi) coordinates.  This command
%also determines (Pxy), (Pxz), and (Pyz): the xy-, xz-, and yz-projections
%of the point (P).
%syntax: \tdplotsetcoord{Coordinate name without parentheses}{r}{\theta}{\phi}
\tdplotsetcoord{P}{\rvec}{\thetavec}{\phivec}

%draw figure contents
%--------------------

%draw the main coordinate system axes
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x''$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y''$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z''$};

%draw a vector from origin to point (P) 
\draw[-stealth,color=black] (O) -- (P) node[midway,above] {$r$};

%draw projection on xy plane, and a connecting line
\draw[dashed, color=red] (O) -- (Pxy);
\draw[dashed, color=red] (P) -- (Pxy);

%draw the angle \phi, and label it
%syntax: \tdplotdrawarc[coordinate frame, draw options]{center point}{r}{angle}{label options}{label}
\tdplotdrawarc{(O)}{0.2}{0}{\phivec}{anchor=north}{$\alpha$}


%set the rotated coordinate system so the x'-y' plane lies within the
%"theta plane" of the main coordinate system
%syntax: \tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{\phi}
\tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{\phivec}

%draw theta arc and label, using rotated coordinate system
\tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(0,0,0)}{0.5}{\thetavec}{90}{anchor=south west}{$\beta$}

%draw some dashed arcs, demonstrating direct arc drawing
\draw[thin,tdplot_rotated_coords] (\rvec,0,0) arc (0:180:\rvec);



\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I saw examples with similar results, like http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/map-projections/, but they are a little bit overkill in my case.

Note: I also tried adding

```
\fill[ball color=white, opacity=0.2] (0,0,0) circle (\rvec);
```

at the end of the code, but this of course resulted in a projected circle (elliptical).

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: I've experimented a little bit, therefore I didn't upload the right code. the radius of the sphere was 0.6 and is now replaced by \rvec.

Comment: in what sense doesn't it match?

Comment: The black arc should be a boundary of the sphere.

The sphere should be between the start and end point of the arc on the z'' axis.

Comment: Maybe it is indeed correct, I should first set an isometric view.

Comment: Yes indeed, you're right.

Answer (score 6):

In isometric view things are more clear. Problem solved.

[image: Correct view]

The code (mainly the Hein template):

```
%% Copyright 2009 Jeffrey D. Hein
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
% The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
% version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status `maintained'.
% 
% The Current Maintainer of this work is Jeffrey D. Hein.
%
% This work consists of the files 3dplot.sty and 3dplot.tex

%Description
%-----------
%3dplot.tex - an example file demonstrating the use of the 3dplot.sty package.

%Created 2009-11-07 by Jeff Hein.  Last updated: 2009-11-09
%----------------------------------------------------------

%Update Notes
%------------

%2009-11-07: Created file along with 3dplot.sty package


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}   %TikZ is required for this to work.  Make sure this exists before the next line

\usepackage{3dplot} %requires 3dplot.sty to be in same directory, or in your LaTeX installation

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}  %generates a tightly fitting border around the work
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2mm}

\begin{document}

%Angle Definitions
%-----------------

%set the plot display orientation
%synatax: \tdplotsetdisplay{\theta_d}{\phi_d}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{45}{135}

%define polar coordinates for some vector
%TODO: look into using 3d spherical coordinate system
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rvec}{.8}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\thetavec}{45}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\phivec}{60}

%start tikz picture, and use the tdplot_main_coords style to implement the display 
%coordinate transformation provided by 3dplot
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,tdplot_main_coords]

% Teken eerst de bol
\shade[tdplot_screen_coords,ball color = white] (0,0) circle (\rvec);

%set up some coordinates 
%-----------------------
\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);

%determine a coordinate (P) using (r,\theta,\phi) coordinates.  This command
%also determines (Pxy), (Pxz), and (Pyz): the xy-, xz-, and yz-projections
%of the point (P).
%syntax: \tdplotsetcoord{Coordinate name without parentheses}{r}{\theta}{\phi}
\tdplotsetcoord{P}{\rvec}{\thetavec}{\phivec}

%draw figure contents
%--------------------

%draw the main coordinate system axes
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x''$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y''$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z''$};

%draw a vector from origin to point (P) 
\draw[-stealth,color=black] (O) -- (P) node[midway,above] {$r$};

%draw projection on xy plane, and a connecting line
\draw[dashed, color=red] (O) -- (Pxy);
\draw[dashed, color=red] (P) -- (Pxy);

%draw the angle \phi, and label it
%syntax: \tdplotdrawarc[coordinate frame, draw options]{center point}{r}{angle}{label options}{label}
\tdplotdrawarc{(O)}{0.2}{0}{\phivec}{anchor=north}{$\alpha$}


%set the rotated coordinate system so the x'-y' plane lies within the
%"theta plane" of the main coordinate system
%syntax: \tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{\phi}
\tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{\phivec}

%draw theta arc and label, using rotated coordinate system
\tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(0,0,0)}{0.5}{\thetavec}{90}{anchor=south west}{$\beta$}

%de slechte
%test
\tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(0,0,0)}{\rvec}{-180}{180}{anchor=south west}{$\gamma$}



\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out.  Would you mind posting your code so that I can see what it is that you did to get it to work?

Comment: Yes, of course. It still is the Hein template, only with some minor changes.

Comment: In Overleaf, it worked by replacing `\usepackage{3dplot}` with `\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}`.